# html css layout with header div who's height is not known and a body div to fill remaining space possible?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a html/css layout, which has a div#header and div#body as direct children of body tag. I want div#body to fill the remaining space and I do not want to use JavaScript. I know it is possible if you know the exact height of the div#header. But i do not want to fix that.

example with fixed div#header

```
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        div {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #header {
            position: relative;
            <!-- i want to remove height because i want the header to size itself 
                 dependent on it's content -->
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #body {
            <!-- I want to make the body position relative and set top to 0 
                 but that does not work as expected.-->
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;

            margin: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: green;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="body">body</div>
</body>
```

Please let me know if there is any alternative which uses divs and css.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can only do this with display:table, or absolute positioning. Why not put the header inside the content div, then make content 100% height?

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. This should serve as a "framework" where i want to load modules into. the modules would usee #body as their content area. if they paint a div with 100% height that should be relative to content's height and content's height should be dependent on header's height. If the clients content would be higher than the conten area only the content area should become scrollablebut the header should always be visible.

Comment: are the css class editable i mean may i change some values.

Comment: @user1826280 i have updated my answer and that is fulfilling your requirements, i think. I am expecting an acceptance for this if this helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `min-height` of the body div to `100%` to stretch out the body div (I've changed the body bg color to make it more obvious).

However, I'm not 100% clear on your second requirement (`<!-- I want to make the body position relative and set top to 0 but that does not work as expected.-->`)

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ESH7/1/)

Comment: in fact this was just my try to make it work but failed. I simply want the header to be always visible no matter how high he becomes dependent on his content and the #body to fill the remaining space so i can make #body's overflow scrollable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated answer: what i have done is to **make the parent html and body to display as a table** and other **divs to have properties of table row** and this css will make them capture the whole screen area.

> **Now i have given the header height of auto.**

and

> **#body is inheriting the other space.**

Try this: http://jsbin.com/ezozeb/5/edit

```
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display:table;
}

#header {
  background-color: red;
  display:table-row;
  height:auto;
}
#body {
  background-color: green;
  display:table-row;
  height:inherit;
}
```

Comment: This is very close but i still have to set a height for the header. I would like the header to take as much space as needed and as less as possible. How is that achievable with your solution?

Comment: +1 JaiPSah is almost there - I believe you also need to make the header fixed. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ESH7/30/)?

Comment: yes but this is expandable with the content length. you can check in the jsbin link.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, delete the height and width of the body element.

You can use page wrappers to make that happen:

```
#PageWrapper
{
  width: 844px;
  background-color: ##4628C4;
  margin: auto;
}

#PageContentWrapper
{
  width: 659px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

The pagecontentwrapper sets the minimum height to 500px.
In html you can then assign these identifiers to the body and divs

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link...>
  </head>
  <body id="PageWrapper">

    <div id="PageContentWrapper">
      Content of the body
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

If you want to make a div scrollable, you should define a height and/or width and add this to the css:

```
overflow-x:auto; <!--horizontal-->
overflow-y:auto; <!--vertical-->
```

For example, if you set the pagewrappers height to 1000 (not the min-heigt) and overflow-y: auto; then the scrollbars will appear when content get out of bounds.

If you want to make the header always on top, you should apply something like this:

```
#PageWrapper
{
  width: 844px;
  background-color: ##4628C4;
  margin: auto;
}

#Header
{
  background-color:#aaaaaa;
  width: 844px;
  height: 240px;
}

#PageContentWrapper
{
  width: 659px;
  height: 700px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;

  padding: 10px;
}
```

and in html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link...>
  </head>
<body id="PageWrapper">
  <div id=Header>
    Headertext
  </div>  
  <div id="PageContentWrapper">
    Content of the body
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the height from the html, body is what I intended to say

Comment: sorry if i articulate myself so unclear. I am not a native english speaker. But I can not see any relation between this answer and my question. Thx for explenation

Comment: Don't worry about it... My native language is dutch, so I know how you feel ;)
You won't get any bad comments about your English on this forum!
By the way, the last example in my answer should partially do what you want, it'll keep the header on top and make the content scrollable. The reason why you can't use percentages for height or width is because it will wrap the div or body around the content and not stretch it to the bounds of the screen.